# rotate a layout without using animation

Tags: android, android-layout, rotation

I'm trying to rotate hole layout by this code:

```
RelativeLayout rll = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.relativeLayout1);
rll.setRotation(21);
```

how can I set rotation center?I don't want to use left bottom corner as rotation center,because some parts of rotated layout is out of the view!!
(I don't want to use animation. bcz my buttons don't work correctly with it)

Answer (score 1):

The answer is here

[Is there any way to rotate a button without using animation in android 2.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8047422/is-there-any-way-to-rotate-a-button-without-using-animation-in-android-2-1)

here

[Rotate a bitmap in android about a point without animation of view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3119416/rotate-a-bitmap-in-android-about-a-point-without-animation-of-view)

or here

[Rotating a view in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1930963/rotating-a-view-in-android)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure i understand what you are asking but try this:

```
 int w = r11.getWidth();
 int h = r11.getHeight();

 r11.setRotation(21f);
 r11.setTranslationX((w - h) / 2);
 r11.setTranslationY((h - w) / 2);
```